# "failed to initialize plugin" after updating tinymce from 4 to version 5?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

I already updated tinymce to verion 5 but it seems an error occur caused by its plugin. It refers to each plugins like "advlist/plugin.min.js"

Failed to initialize plugin: advlist Error: editor.addButton has been removed in tinymce 5x, use editor.ui.registry.addButton or editor.ui.registry.addToggleButton or editor.ui.registry.addSplitButton instead

By the way, I'm using zendframework 2.